# LockToken expires before LockUntilUtc time in azure service bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using windows azure service bus for messaging. We have created web api to pull the messages from service bus. Mobile app is using this web api for getting messages. We are using PeekLock mode in subscription client and the lockduration is 5 minutes.

On client side if messages takes more than 5 minute to process then message will unlock. So before it unlock we want to renew the Lock. So we have created another web api to renew the lock. In web api we are passing the LockToken. But when we use subscriptionClient.RenewMessageLockAsync(new Guid(lockToken)), it throws error "The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue" before the Lock expiration time. We are initiating the renew lock before 1.5 min of message LockUntilUtc time.

My question here is can we renew the message lock before it expirytime? And if yes then why azure service bus throwing lock expired error? Please help me to understand this renew lock things.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the lock manually, but you need to make sure it happens before the server is unlocking it.

Another option, which I personally prefer more, is to use [`OnMessage` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369363.aspx). It allows you to specify [`OnMessageOptions.AutoRenewTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions.autorenewtimeout.aspx) which will be an extension time in case your callback that handles the message is not done. `OnMessage` API will also ensure that extension is invoked if you're about to exceed lock duration. This way you also won't need to have another web API, which sounds a little off.

Have a look at the [recent post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus-onmessage-api) I wrote on this API.

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks for reply. I cannot use subscriptionClient.OneMessage method as it is event driven. Thats why I am using receive method so that I cannot get all the message in a while loop and send back to user.

Comment: Renewing lock manually from the code that processes the incoming message should work. Curious, why do you do it from another process and not the same one that handles the message?

Comment: Hi Sean, I cannot do this as the messages will consume by iPad application and there is not direct api for objective C or Swift. So that is why I have created rest web api instead of using azure service bus rest api.

Comment: Could you laverage the REST API? Documentation:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj839746.aspx